# Restful web api not accessing from mobile devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

After developing Web API rest services i noticed that it is accessible only from computers.In mobile it is showing web page cannot be displayed is there any setting should be added to access from mobile ?

Comment: hosted Web api  is on public or private network?

Comment: do you have WiFi setup to access it from external device?

Comment: yes i got your point.Will change to public thanks for quick support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computers are connected with internal network, so they can access your web API. While your mobile device generally connected by your data provider (network provider) so it can't directly access your web api. You can do following:

1. Set up your web api to access it through wifi (internal WiFi setup if you can). and then connect your mobile to that wifi and try to access.

Or

1. Publish/deploy your web API on public network and then access it from your mobile device.